# Meaning of 奴のが?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-の, particle-が, manga

This is from Death Note-One Shot Especial, Ryuk says this sentence

> そういうのが得意って奴のが向いてるかも。

what is the function of the の in 奴のが?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> そういうのが得意って奴**のが**向いてるかも。

means

> そういうのが得意って奴**の[方]{ほう}が**向いてるかも。

XXのが～ is a colloquial, a bit slangy way of saying XXの[方]{ほう}が～. I think it's a pretty new usage.

Examples:

> 「結婚するなら、カッコいい人より優しい人**のが**いいかな。」
> 「マイナンバーカードって、持ってない人**のが**多いと思う。」